# Hashtag instead of the dollar sign ssh shell

Tags: linux, shell, centos, putty

Hello I got a server with Centos 5 (64 bits) installed and when I'm connecting with putty after entering the user root and the password I get a hashtag instead of a dollar sign I'm confuse.

```
[root@mokmeuh ~]#
```

Also it's seems that alot of command don't work like

```
[root@mokmeuh ~]# $chmod u+x file.sh
```

That's just one but I can't run a shell script or anything like that so I'm confuse and need some help.

Comment: A `#` usually indicates that you are the superuser (i.e. root). Also the `$` is not part of the `chmod ...` command, leave it out.

Comment: $ is a part of variables, though.

Comment: The `#` (hash, or 'pound' if you're American, but a pound is '£'!) is used to warn you that mistakes are dangerous.  A mistyped command can do serious damage.  If you don't like the `#`, you can set `PS1='$ '` or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, hashtag usually says that you're root.
Normal users have the dollar sign.

But you shouldn't write the dollar sign in front of your commands. Just leave it.

Comment: hahaahhaahaha thank you I switched them .... silly me ... thank you again